# Android How to pass real time data up the stack from local service to the activity?

Tags: android

I have a local service that will need to wait for a response and when it gets the response immediately update the activity with that information.  So the activity will not poll a service method but the moment the local service gets some data it has to inform that activity immediately somehow.

So Activity--binds-->LocalService <------>(RemoteService separate process).  So I know I could just package it up in an intent and pass it up to the activity ... but is that the best/only option.  How else might one communicate up the stack from the local service to the activity thats invoking the local service?  Keep in mind I already have the local service binding to a remote separate process service which runs forever in the background and periodically sends realtime data to the local service.  Thanks

Comment: build ContentProvider extend ContentObserver and use ContentResolver.notifyChange to inform ContentObserver that data was changed

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the `handler` object of the activity to service thru `setter()` and using this object you can update the change in the activity.

Comment: getter() - setter() that we use to set and get values.

Comment: ok.  so your suggesting maintaining a reference inside the service to the activity?  is that a good idea?